# How to set default value for option in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This has been asked before, but I can't find the answer for my specific question. Here is the tree of components.
SELECT
|
UPLOAD
|
PAGE

So the select component, gets passed down to the upload component, then the upload component gets passed down to the display page.

I need the option to have a default value depending on what type of document the user uploads.

```
<select name="{{$ctrl.id}}" id="{{$ctrl.id}}" ng-model="$ctrl.lovModel" ng-disabled="$ctrl.lovDisabled" class="form-control" ng-style="{{$ctrl.style}}" ng-required="$ctrl.ngRequired" ng-change="$ctrl.onChange($ctrl.lovModel, $ctrl.repeatIndex)"
        ng-options="option.optionValue as option.description for option in $ctrl.list | orderBy:'sortOrder'">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
```

```
angular.
  module('olsLov').
  component('olsLov', {
    templateUrl: _commonPath+'/ols-lov/ols-lov.template.html',
    bindings: {
      lovModel: '=',
      properties: '=',
      lovChange: '<',
      ngRequired: '<',
      parentValue: '@',
      lovDisabled: '<',
      lov: '@',
      style: '@',
      repeatIndex: '<',
    },
    controller: ['$attrs', 'LovData',
      function TestListController($attrs, $LovData) {
  
        var self = this;
........code goes on.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of the select’s ng-model to the desired default value. This is most probably in your controller.